# Creating scrollbars in an HTML PaperJS canvas element for use with paper.view.zoom

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, scrollbar, zooming, paperjs

- We have a PaperJS canvas that is set to 100% width/height
- Users can zoom and pan
- Users can add content to the canvas at various places within the canvas regardless of zoom/pan state
- We want to add scrollbars to the canvas like those used in Figma when there is content outside the currently viewable area

When a user zooms in/out or pans with a PaperJS canvas, they're not moving the actual canvas in the DOM or increasing the canvas element's size. Instead, they're changing the viewing relationship to content within the canvas element.

Thus the scrollbars need to be created in the canvas element but there doesn't appear to be a way to lock the scrollbars ratio. For example, if the scrollbars are in the canvas context and you zoom in, you're zooming on all of the canvas content and the scrollbars change in size as well. It seems like the only solution would be to have some sort of listener in place that always sets their size, position, etc in relation to the zoom/pan state of the canvas, which seems like a lot of extra code. Has anyone come across a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do what you commented on the end of your question.

- Set initial height of scroll bar to `const scrollHeight = view.height`
- Create an update function and attach it to `view.onFrame`
- In update function update scroll objects height depending on current zoom `scrollObject.bounds.height = scrollHeight / view.zoom`
- You can then determine the scroll bars handle position by getting the position of the highest objects `obj.bounds.top`, the lowest objects bottom bounds `obj.bounds.bottom`, and finally use the current view position center to calculate the handle position `view.bounds.center`

Comment: Ah that makes sense for panning. I assume the update function would also need something for controlling the scale of the element when zooming in and out. 

I approached it from another angle using paperscopes to control various canvas elements in the same DOM

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/christate/qua6snzw/166/

Comment: This is a hack job just to see if o could “lock” elements while messing with others. There’s a lot to be desired but it “works.” Thoughts on this approach?

Comment: Seems like a valid approach, you just need to track the handles position and also make the scrolling functional.  You might also just want to create a new `paper.layer` and place the scroll bar in that instead of on a seperate canvas.  You would just need to update the scroll bars position in the update function too.  `scrollbarObject.position = view.bounds.right.subtract(10,0)`.  Your method is fine do.

Comment: I thought about putting it in another layer but wouldn't that be subject to the scaling that takes place on the view when I zoom in/out? I saw a comment in their github about using a transform false property on layers but the documentation doesn't show that property. I'll def give that a shot though, would be cleaner  than managing a bunch of scopes.

Comment: it would indeed scale, thats why you would have to changle its size with `scrollObject.bounds.height = scrollHeight / view.zoom` in the update function.